# SignalR .net Core. Not getting signalr.js?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to start a signalR application, I've downloaded the signalR client with through the nuget packages.

In all of the tutorials they are refering to signalr.js in the lib/signalr/ folder.
But when I downloaded it, I did not get any updates in my /lib folder??
There is no signalR.js ?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: yeah i see it. Also I just noticed that i have the signalr.js in the folder but i can't see it in visual studio? I have it in the node modules but that folder isn't visible in vs?

Comment: yeah i copied the folder to /lib :) Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft introduced a new Library Manager called `LibMan` for managing client side libraries. Use this as follows:

`wwwroot > lib > Add > Client-Side Library`

[image]
[image]

Its also available on 
[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr) and you can download this as follows:

```
npm init -y
npm install @aspnet/signalr
```

For more information : [Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Yeh! :) This is the Microsoft suggested solution with newly introduced `LibMan` library!

Comment: Moreover using this solution file wouldn't be hidden anymore. Your file will  be directly added to your folder:)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The folder was hidden in visual studio. It was in node_modules, were needed to copy it to the wwwroot/lib folder.